# Website Nearly Complete on Squarespace: Need Help Centering Video

Tags: css, html

I'm an undergrad Computer Science student. I started a volunteer internship for a local nonprofit about a year ago as their Web Development Intern. I created the whole site and know basic HTML/CSS.

However, I've been having trouble centering a video inside an iFrame. Can someone please offer any guidance on how to center the following code? I tried a number of tactics using everything on w3schools. I haven't been able to get it to work. It seems that HTML5 now supports direct video insertion? Would it better to use that instead of an iFrame? Here is the original code.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzsZKVriXxNbXdjUjhYRVVHV1k/preview" width="640" height="480">
</iframe>
```

If needed I can also show you a pic on how it is showing up in the browser with the above code.

Oh and also, I just posted the video on YouTube in hopes of being able to better "emb" it into the individual page on Squarespace.

EDIT: Here is the link to the page. http://www.federationnc.org/publications-1/

Comment: You need to post your HTML, CSS, and a link to the website would be helpful

Comment: you can't center the video "INSIDE" the iframe because everything inside the iframe is outside of what you can control via your stylesheet.  Ideally the iframe would just be the video, then you can center the container on your page.

Comment: @ImagineWebDesign The HTML is above. Edited the post to show link.

Comment: What do you want to with the video?

Comment: @Nickfmc can you offer any guidance on how to center it without using an iFrame then? I'm confused about your last sentence. The video is the only thing inside the iFrame.

Comment: @ImagineWebDesign I want to center the video on the page by adjusting the HTML code above in the post.

Comment: @Nickfmc Do you even read the post? The HTML has been up there since the start. Added the link immediately after. I got it done - thanks anyway.

Comment: wow calm down! I read it right away before you had the EDIT in there ok! sorry for helping, as soon as I noticed I tried to remove my comment, and the iframe embedd is not the site code, no one can do anything with that.

Comment: @nickfmc squarespace is a what you see if what you get web development tool. They allow you to add blocks and create the html for you, which is rather nice because it scales it to whatever device it is being displayed upon very nicely. With that being said, the code above is a Squarespace "block" called "Code Editor" - that is the only html inserted in that block. Now I understand that I can also add css code inside these blocks to mess with the individual snippets of html code.

Comment: @ImagineWebDesign Thank you so much. In the code block in Squarespace, I can just add that brief and simple Custom CSS below along with the iframe to center it. Thank you so much.

Comment: It wasn't a problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just center it like you normally would a block element, with `margin:auto;`:

```
iframe{
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

Result:
[image]
Yes, HTML5 allows direct insertion, but it can be a pain to use a video format that is supported in all browsers, using a YouTube embed is probably the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To make a more user-friendly video on Squaerspace. Instead of adding HTML code to be embed onto the site...I uploaded the video to Youtube then just added the video to the page using Squarespace's built-in functions.

It looks great now.